# angularjs radio button defaut value not selected

Tags: angularjs

I have a radio button which works fine if I remove `Angularjs` but if I added the `Angularjs` code it doesn't have a default selected/checked value.

I have the same `ng-model="frm.mode"` but still nothing is selected by default.

HTML

```
<div class="border-bottom border-color-1 border-dotted-bottom">
    <div class="p-3" id="basicsHeadingThree">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="thirdstylishRadio1" ng-model="frm.mode" value="DELIVERY" name="mode" checked>
            <label class="custom-control-label form-label" for="thirdstylishRadio1"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#basicsCollapseThree"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="basicsCollapseThree">
                Delivery
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="basicsCollapseThree" class="collapse show border-top border-color-1 border-dotted-top bg-dark-lighter"
        aria-labelledby="basicsHeadingThree"
        data-parent="#basicsAccordion1">
        <div class="p-4">
            cash on delivery
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Card -->

<!-- Card -->
<div class="border-bottom border-color-1 border-dotted-bottom">
    <div class="p-3" id="basicsHeadingOne">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="stylishRadio1" ng-model="frm.mode" value="PICKUP" name="mode">
            <label class="custom-control-label form-label" for="stylishRadio1"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#basicsCollapseOnee"
                aria-expanded="true"
                aria-controls="basicsCollapseOnee">
                Pickup
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="basicsCollapseOnee" class="collapse border-top border-color-1 border-dotted-top bg-dark-lighter"
        aria-labelledby="basicsHeadingOne"
        data-parent="#basicsAccordion1">
        <div class="p-4">
            pickup order
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to set your model = value of the radio which you want to select by default in controller

Comment: I don't understand, could you elaborate more?

Comment: Here is the demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview&preview

Comment: it's empty preview

Comment: Sorry I created a link on codesandbox for you https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-shaw-fnze8?file=/index.html

Comment: wow thank you, you can post it to the answer so I can accept it

Comment: Haha :) Okay. Glad to hear that helps